# Drupal Colorbox with Prezi iframe

Tags: javascript

I have a Prezi file and the embedded code is like this:

```
<iframe src="http://prezi.com/embed/id-of-the-file/?bgcolor=ffffff&amp;lock_to_path=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autohide_ctrls=0&amp;features=undefined&amp;disabled_features=undefined&amp;html5=1" width="550" height="400" frameBorder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozAllowFullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have installed Colorbox and activated Colorbox load and Colorbox inline in the module settings.

How can I open this file with Colorbox?

I've created a link and tried like this:

```
<a class="colorbox-load" href="http://prezi.com/embed/id-of-the-file/?bgcolor=ffffff&amp;lock_to_path=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autohide_ctrls=0&amp;features=undefined&amp;disabled_features=undefined&amp;html5=1?width=500&amp;height=500&amp;iframe=true">open in Colorbox (iframe)</a>
```

The colorbox is opening, but it shows "This content failed to load".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your link by concatenating `width=500&amp;height=500&amp;iframe=true` with an `?` instead with another `&amp;`
So the working link would be:

```
<a class="colorbox-load" href="http://prezi.com/embed/id-of-the-file/?bgcolor=ffffff&amp;lock_to_path=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autohide_ctrls=0&amp;features=undefined&amp;disabled_features=undefined&amp;html5=1&amp;width=500&amp;height=500&amp;iframe=true">open in Colorbox (iframe)</a>
```

Comment: I've tried with your solution and it's working great!

Comment: glad to help you!